# vsto automatic web update

Tags: url, installation, vsto, clickonce

I have developed a VSTO add-in for Outlook and can install it from a ClickOnce setup.exe on an end-user's PC, but I do not understand how to implement an installer that will subsequently automatically update the add-in from a web location (URL). The add-in is for 'external' customers, so I cannot push the add-in to the end-users' PCs.

I suspect that I am missing or misunderstanding something fundamental, but can't find the solution (I believe that I have read all the MS documentation on VSTO ClickOnce configurations).

I know that in the Visual Studio publish settings, I need to specify an "Installation Folder URL" for the updated VSTO files, but it seems as though I am in a Catch-22 situation because the VSTO will only update if it was *originally* installed from the specified URL. If I upload the initial installation files to the URL, so the end-user can download the setup.exe file (for their first install), then they cannot run it, because the setup.exe is being run from the end-users PC, not the URL (i.e. "location is not trusted"). On the other hand, if I create a setup.exe to run on the end-user's PC, it installs just fine, but then it doesn't know to update from the URL.

What I have achieved on my development machine is:

Run the VSTO in Debug mode (with the update URL specified in the publish settings), so Outlook loads the add-in. Then, stop debugging, publish an update and upload it to the URL, reload Outlook (from the desktop); the add-in updates automatically from the URL. This demonstrates that the auto-update is working from the URL.

I am wondering if the automatic updating from a URL is only intended for situations when the VSTO has been deployed internally within an organisation via a push mechanism, and then the add-in subsequently updates automatically from the URL.

The bottom-line question is, how can an 'external' end-user first install an add-in, so that it subsequently updates from the specified URL?